# What is a formal word for "typicality"?

Tags: synonyms

Consider the sentence:

> *Although design plans were not required, they are included in the appendix to demonstrate the typicality of our design*.

I want to reassure/emphasize that the underlying ideas of the design are not something complicated/unique but very,very typical indeed. However, I don't want to use informal phrases like *... how typical our design is*.

Anyone knows of any good synonyms?

Comment: hum-drum, banal, run-of-the-mill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conventionality](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/conventional) is listed in LDOCE as a noun derived from the adjective *conventional* (not exactly a synonym, but related to typical). But when you try to look *conventionality* up, the same dictionary doesn't provide a definition, just refers to *conventional*.

Comment: Despite your dictionary's shortcomings, "conventionality" - as in: 'consistent with  the usual', would be a good fit in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me to be quite formal.

See examples of

["typicality of our"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22typicality%20of%20our%20design%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22typicality%20of%20our%22)

at Google Books.